# Determine flags that were given for packages installed with homebrew

Tags: homebrew

Is there a way to check what flags were given when a package was installed with homebrew?

For example, the emacs formula has an absurd number of flags. If I did

```
brew install emacs --with-glib --with-librsvg
```

I would like to later determine that for the homebrew installation of emacs I gave the flags `--with-glib --with-librsvg` and not any other flags.

Test case with lua package:

Before installing the package, info shows all options.

```
$ brew info lua
lua: stable 5.2.3 (bottled)
http://www.lua.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/lua.rb
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-completion
    Enables advanced readline support
--without-sigaction
    Revert to ANSI signal instead of improved POSIX sigaction
```

I install the package with just the `--with-completion` flag.

```
$ brew install lua --with-completion
==> Downloading http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.3.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading http://luajit.org/patches/lua-5.2.0-advanced_readline.patch
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading http://lua-users.org/files/wiki_insecure/power_patches/5.2/lua-5
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file Makefile
patching file src/Makefile
patching file src/lua.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 231 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 559 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 575 (offset -4 lines).
patching file src/lua.c
==> make macosx INSTALL_TOP=/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.3_1 INSTALL_MAN=/usr/local
==> make install INSTALL_TOP=/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.3_1 INSTALL_MAN=/usr/loca
  /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.3_1: 13 files, 312K, built in 6 seconds
```

After installing the package, info shows all options, including those I did not use. The command does acknowledge that the package was built from source and not poured from a bottle.

```
$ brew info lua
lua: stable 5.2.3 (bottled)
http://www.lua.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.3_1 (13 files, 312K) *
  Built from source with: --with-completion
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/lua.rb
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-completion
    Enables advanced readline support
--without-sigaction
    Revert to ANSI signal instead of improved POSIX sigaction
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a package is built from source the flags that were used to build are shown when you do `brew info <package>`.

In this case: `brew info emacs | grep "Built from source"`

Comment: The output of brew info always lists all available options for the formula, not the options used if the package was installed.

Comment: That's not true. The info specifies if the package was installed from a bottle or built from source, and if it was built from source it shows the flags that were used.

Comment: Edited OP with an example in which, as far as I can tell, info does not specify the flags used for a package built from source.

Comment: Oh oops, I see it and your grep command makes sense now.

Answer (score 6):

There is a file in `/usr/local/Cellar` underneath each package that is called `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json`, e.g. for `gawk`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gawk/4.1.3/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
```

that defines how the package was installed. I think the correct way to access it is with

```
brew info --json=v1 <packagename>
```

e.g.

```
brew info --json=v1 gnuplot
```

That spews out loads of stuff, but if you send it through `jq` (JSON Processor - handily available via `homebrew`) you can select out the options you used to install the package like this (checking the `gnuplot` package):

```
brew info --json=v1 gnuplot | jq '.[].installed[0].used_options'
[
    "--with-qt"
]
```

which tells me I installed `gnuplot` using:

```
brew install --with-qt gnuplot
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: `for package in $(brew list); do echo -n "brew install $package "; for item in $(brew info --json=v1 $package | jq -r '.[0].installed[0].used_options | .[]'); do echo -n "$item "; done;  echo ; done 2>/dev/null`

can be used to output a list of brew install commands that you can use elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Another useful tool is [`homebrew-bundler`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle). Once installed via `brew tap Homebrew/bundle`, you can run `brew bundle dump` and it will create a Brewfile file that lists all of the packages you have installed along with any additional args used to install them.

Comment: This is indeed a nice option.  And, to edit the `Brewfile` and check it into your dotfiles repo makes it easy to "setup" new machines.  Though, it lists all packages including all dependencies.  I'm currently having to parse the list from a `brew leaves` list that lists only the top-level installed packages.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little bash function that returns the flags irrespective of if package was built from source or not.

```
function brew_options()
{
    [ "$#" -ne 1 ] && >&2 echo -e "$FUNCNAME requires only 1 option, the package name" && return 1

    local item=$1
    local opts

    ## Check if package installed
    [ -n "$(brew ls --versions $item)" ] || ( >&2 echo -e "$item is not installed" && return 1 )

    set -o pipefail

    ## Get options if built from source
    if ! opts="$(brew info $item | grep 'Built from source with:' | sed 's/^[ \t]*Built from source with:/ /g; s/\,/ /g')" ; then
        # If not built from source, get options from brew metadata
        opts="$(brew info --json=v1 $item | jq -ec '.[].installed[0].used_options' | awk '{print substr($0, 2, length($0) - 2)}' | sed 's/,/ /g;s/"//g')"
    fi

    ## If we're able to get options and its just not spaces echo it 
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && [[ ! -z "${opts// }" ]]; then
        echo "$opts"
    fi

    set +o pipefail

}
```

To use this bash function within a bash script write

```
 brew_options PKGNAME
```

where `PKGNAME` is the desired homebrew package name.  You can also iterate through all installed homebrew packages within a bash script as

```
 # Command to generate install script
 PKGS=$(brew list)

 # iterate through all packges
 for PKG in $PKGS; do

   echo $PKG `brew_options $PKG`

 done
```

.

Comment: depencency note: `jq` command-line JSON processor